# Is this a known issue with the centering of eqnarray?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

In this example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray*}
A&=&B,\\
C&=&D,\\
E&=&F,
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
A&=&\mathord{B,}\\
C&=&\mathord{D,}\\
E&=&\mathord{F,}
\end{eqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

I would think that the two `eqnarray*`'s would come out perfectly aligned on the = signs, but instead the top `eqnarray*` comes out slightly to the left of the bottom one (the difference is less than 1 point). I assume this has to do with the fact that the lines in the top `eqnarray*` end with punctuation symbols, while the lines in the bottom `eqnarray*` end with ordinary symbols. Is this a known issue?

By the way, if I load the `eqnarray` package from [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eqnarray209), the excessive space around the middle column is removed, but my centering issue remains.

Comment: Do you know question [eqnarray vs align?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align?rq=1)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `\showoutput` to debug this kind of thing.

In the first, because the `,` is in the middle of an expression there is

```
......\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.66663
```

after it but because in the second it is at the end of a `{}` subexpression there is no such space, so the first expression is that much wider, which when centred shifts things by half that amount, which as you say is less than a point.

---

On closer inspection you will see that the extra space is *only* added on the first two rows as the `,` only adds space if it is not at the end, `\\` acts like `{}` but `\end{eqnarray*}` does not. Compare `$B,{}$` to `$B,$`. this is arguably a bug in `eqnarray` but it would be hard to change it now.

Adding

```
\makeatletter
\def\foo#1!!{\def\@eqncr{\ifnum0=`{\fi}{\ifnum0=`}\fi#1}}
\expandafter\foo\@eqncr!!
\makeatother
```

fixes it (I think)

With a comma the spacing change is just at the end so affects the centering of the whole alignment but isn't that noticeable. With `+` though it is rather more obvious that the last row is different:

Perhaps we should fix this in `fixltx2e`....

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\showoutput
\begin{eqnarray*}
A&=&B+\\
C&=&D+\\
E&=&F+
\end{eqnarray*}

\makeatletter
\def\foo#1!!{\def\@eqncr{\ifnum0=`{\fi}{\ifnum0=`}\fi#1}}
\expandafter\foo\@eqncr!!
\let\@seqncr=\@eqncr

\begin{eqnarray*}
A&=&B+\\
C&=&D+\\
E&=&F+
\end{eqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

---

actually I think it's OK to use simple `\bgroup` here so:

```
\def\foo#1!!{\def\@eqncr{\egroup\bgroup#1}}
```

rather than the special `\halign`  trick groups.